# Math in Javascript to Node.js produces false output

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

Here's what I'm doing.

```js
    var str_1 = parseInt("2200")
    var str_2 = parseInt("200")
   
    var output = str_1 + str_2
        
    var a = output;
    var b = 10
    var c = (parseFloat(a)*parseFloat(b))/100;
    var results  = parseFloat(c);

    console.log("the result: " + results);
        
    var final_output = str_2 - results
        
    console.log("Completion: " + final_output);
```

Console logs:

```
[Log] the result: 240 
[Log] Completion: -40
```

Correct. Exactly expected output but doing the same thing in NodeJS yields the following output

```
[Log] the result: 260 
[Log] Completion: -60
```

Not the same as my Javascript result.

#### UPDATE

Just for this question i used plain numbers,

```
    var str_1 = 2200
    var str_2 = 200

    var output = str_1 + str_2

    var a = output;
    var b = 10
    var c = (parseFloat(a)*parseFloat(b))/100;
    var results  = parseFloat(c);

    console.log("the result: " + results);

    var final_output = str_2 - results

    console.log("Completion: " + final_output);
```

Well, still gives the incorrect output. What to do here?

> I'm trying to take 10% off of `output` so `b` is the percent here, and then. `str_2 - results`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188700/discussion-on-question-by-rawand-ahmad-math-in-javascript-to-node-js-produces-fa).

Answer (score 0):

### BIG UPDATE

Turns out as @CrazyMerlin mentioned, I was using node.js v6 on Google Cloud Functions, Just updated to v8 beta and everything is working just fine now.

Thank you everyone for the incredible support in minutes :)